# What kind of statics hyperboleans may have?

Tags: geometry

Picture that you are a flat-lander and live in the hyperbolic plane. In your land there are flat horses which pull flat carts in arbitrary directions. Total chaos! So there are forces and it is getting more and more important to know what force could balance some other forces - horses. You read an esoteric book on worlds where there are vectors. You cannot imagine those things -- of course. However, based on your fresh knowledge on vectors you have to work out statics. (Dacapitation upon failure.)

What would you do?

Comment: There's a lot of things you could mean by vectors, but I'm not sure which of them would mean that "the hyperbolic plane has no vectors." If you think of vectors as a direction and magnitude for the purposes of statics and dynamics, then that seems to survive. Why wouldn't it? Maybe what you are getting at is that vector algebra no longer applies to them, so you can't add them, etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly: direction (of a tangent something) and magnitude will survive. Let's take fish scales. Our fish scales are straight. I suppose that their fish scales are straight as well. You can gauge the magnitude in different directions. OK. But how to "sum" the magnitudes and the directions to get the balancing magnitude and direction? That is the question.

Comment: OK, then I can see the the spirit of your question better. I'll have to think about it...